# C# How to print out log to console?

Tags: c#

I would like to print out something similar to this:[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nqo9.jpg)

onto the console.

I have this code in my "ILogger" class:

```
namespace GameOfChanceSimulator
{
    public interface ILogger //public added
    {
        void Info(string message);
        void Errorr(string message);
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to make this ILogger message into something like on the picture...
pls help!

Comment: ok , thats an interface, it doesnt actually "do" stuff you need to implement a class that inherits from it and meets its requirements

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` can be used to output to the console. But as BugFinder mentions, first you will need an actual class in order to write any functioning code.

Comment: please see this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/899992/Logging-with-Microsoft-NET

Comment: I am tempted to edit your question title to "How to implement a logger interface in a console app". There are [many questions with accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+how+to+implement+an+interface+isaccepted%3Ayes) you could check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    public interface ILogger //public added
    {
        void Info(string message);
        void Error(string message);
    }

    public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        public void Error(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {message}");
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Info: {message}");
        }
    }
```

Now you can use the logger like below:

```
ILogger logger = new Logger();

logger.Error("Error12345");
logger.Info("Program has started");
```